# Type defaulting in ghci

Tags: haskell

I am using GHCi as my interpreter,

The specifications for my assignment are to have a list of tuples of `Int`s ie

```
[(Int,Int)]
```

when I type

```
let edges = [(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(2,3)]
```

GHCi  automatically makes the number types `Integer` instead of `Int`, so I can't test my program ie,

```
:t edges
edges :: [(Integer,Integer)]
```

How can I force a definition like that to use `Int`, instead of `Integer`??

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean GHCi rather than hgci, perchance?

Comment: Related links: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules and http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4

Comment: Tokhon Jelvis gave you the answer...but if possible you should change your program to use `Integer` instead of `Int` you should.  `Int` has poorly defined semantics and leads to subtle bugs and scalability problems.  Unless it is in a performance critical loop, use `Integer`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the type when you enter it like this:

```
let edges = [(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(2,3)] :: [(Int, Int)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use the way you usually specify types for functions in programs, but you must fit both expressions in the same interpreter command

```
>let edges :: [(Int, Int)]; edges = [(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(2,3)]
>:t edges
  edges :: [(Int, Int)]
```